# How to report library(multcomp) post-hoc test to your manuscript?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model, post-hoc

I'm running a post-hoc test after GLM model by library(multcomp), the results shows,

```
     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
Fit: glm(formula = survival ~ quality + quantity, family = binomial, 
data = Survival2)

Linear Hypotheses:
                              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
Acartia(-) - Artemia == 0      4.3347     0.8044   5.388   <1e-04 ***
Acartia(+) - Artemia == 0      3.4342     0.7031   4.884   <1e-04 ***
Acartia(+) - Acartia(-) == 0  -0.9005     0.6944  -1.297    0.395    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

How should I report this results to a manuscript? like (z=5.388, p<0.001)? I'm not sure, **should I report the z valu**e?
Thank you.

Comment: Usually the p-value is reported. Many people also use the letter notation as implemented by the `cld` function to indicate non/different groups.

Comment: @RolandThank you for your comment. I decided to  report like (GLM, Tukey's Post-hoc test, P<0.001)